# ssh-agent not persistent after some amount of time (no reboot)

Tags: ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I am using Suse 12 on VM, it is left running and never off/rebooted.

I use TCSH and would call

```
> eval 'ssh-agent -c'
> ssh-add
> <put passphrase here>
```

And then ssh login to servers/github etc works well.

**However**, after a while, say a day after, the ssh-agent stopped working and if i do

```
> ssh-add -l
> error fetching identities for protocol 1: communication with agent failed
> error fetching identities for protocol 2: communication with agent failed
> The agent has no identities.
```

I dont know what the actual time that is between failures. To my knowledge the VM is never rebooted.

I then have to kill the ssh-agent process, and manually restart the process.

Any idea why?

Comment: Need to see the ssh log files, to get any idea of the problem.

Comment: @alimack, I am not sure if i can get ssh log file, i may need to start sshd with different option, i dont have sudo privilege on my VM (managed by admin). However, I starting to notice that what i said as "after a while" may not be true. Now i realize that between one ssh window and the next window (vscode remote ssh), the ssh-agent doesnt work across the sessions. I tried using xterm and ssh-add to the main xterm, then launch gnome-terminal from it, all the terminal tabs carry the same session from the xterm (as in 'ssh-add -l' shows the key being served).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, perhaps I didnt understand the whole picture of the ssh key/ssh-agent. I have my VM which I connect thru somekind of xclient. From that client, I didnt see any setting to do any `ForwardAgent` - the issue above was seen when I use VSCODE remote to the VM and from that VM ssh terminal, I wanted to SSH to another physical server.

I have `ForwardAgent yes` in my SSH config from local (Windows) machine which serves local key. From there, I added local key (on Windows) to the third machine (physical server)'s `authorized_keys` and now it works beautifully.